# Sign Up, Xcode and Databases

Tags: database, xcode, uialertview

I have no clue really where to start or what code to use etc so just want to see if one of you guys could push me in the right direction.

Basically on my app, when the user first ever opens the app I want an alert to prompt them to sign up with their email and name, with this information being sent to a database. But once they have been prompt with this once, the next time they open the app I don't want this to show..

Any help guys!?!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to use cookies if we talk about web app but you have a application for the mobile phone then I would use some of the cashed memory, write value inside which you will check everytime app starts.

But you need to know that this can only work until user deletes memory.

So you are on the good way but what you want to make is not 100% possible if you understand me.

Comment: I am sorry I assumed that you are making mobile app. What application are you making? For what platform?

Answer (score 0):

Your application can have user preferences that are accessed through a NSUserDefaults object.  You can check for the existence of a preference and, if you don't find it, perform your sign up and then create that preference so the sign up will be skipped in the future...assuming the database transaction succeeds.

The other option that comes to mind is validating with the remote database but that depends on what you want to do if the network is unavailable.